# Call a generic function with or without parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a code looking like this:

```
def my_function(obj)
  if obj.type == 'a'
    return [:something]
  elsif obj.type == 'b'
    return []
  elsif obj.type == 'c'
    return [obj]
  elsif obj.type == 'd'
    return [obj]*2
  end
end
```

I want to separate all these `if...elsif` blocks into functions like this:

```
def my_function_with_a
  return [:something]
end

def my_function_with_b
   return []
end

def my_function_with_c(a_parameter)
  return [a_parameter]
end

def my_function_with_d(a_parameter)
  return [a_parameter] * 2
end
```

I call these functions with

```
def my_function(obj)
  send(:"my_function_with_#{obj.type}", obj)
end
```

The problem is that some functions need parameters, others do not. I can easily define `def my_function_with_a(nothing=nil)`, but I'm sure there is a better solution to do this.

@Dogbert had a great idea with `arity`. I have a solution like this:

```
def my_function(obj)
  my_method = self.method("my_function_with_#{obj.type}")
  return (method.arity.zero? ? method.call : method.call(obj))
end
```

Comment: How are you going to use this piece of code? You can get the `arity` of the function, and pass parameters based on that, but the method depends on how do you want to use this.

Comment: This might be an X/Y problem, in that you think you need to do X to achieve Y, but the design you have ended up with has some pathologies - it might be worth sharing your wider design and asking if there are any good patterns that achieve Y more directly

Comment: What is this object? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: @mind.blank This is any object. It's an object having a "type" method, return 'a'...'d'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_function(obj)
  method = method("my_function_with_#{obj.type}")
  method.call(*[obj].first(method.arity))
end
```

Comment: Nice, I like this :) Beautiful Ruby !

Answer (score 3):

Check how to call methods in Ruby, for that I will recommend you this two resources: [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls) and [enter link description here](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/).

Take a special note on optional arguments where you can define a method like this:

```
def method(*args)
end
```

and then you call call it like this:

> method
>
> method(arg1)
>
> method(arg1, arg2)

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(*args)
  [ 'foo' ].push(*args)
end

>> foo
=> [ 'foo' ]
>> foo('bar')
=> [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
>> foo('bar', 'baz')
=> [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
```

Comment: Nice, that was my next addition :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to something like:

```
def my_function_with_foo(bar=nil)
  if bar
    return ['foo', bar]
  else
    return ['foo']
  end
end
```

Now the following will both work:

```
send(:"my_function_with_#{foo_bar}")
=> ['foo']
send(:"my_function_with_#{foo_bar}", "bar")
=> ['foo', 'bar']
```

You can also write it like this if you don't want to use `if/else` and you're sure you'll never need `nil` in the array:

```
def my_function_with_foo(bar=nil)
  return ['foo', bar].compact
end
```

Comment: How about placing all those methods inside the object's class, and use `obj.send(:"my_function_with_#{obj.type}")`. Once inside the class you can do `return [self] *2`, `return [self.attr1, self.attr2]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default value

```
def fun(a_param = nil)
    if a_param
        return ['raboof',a_param]
    else
        return ['raboof']
    end
end
```

or...

```
def fun(a_param : nil)
    if a_param
        return ['raboof',a_param]
    else
        return ['raboof']
    end
end
```

The latter is useful if you have multiple parameters because now when you call it you can just pass in the ones that matter right now.

```
fun(a_param:"Hooray")
```

Comment: I just ask my question because my previous function look like your solution, but with with 15 `if`, `elsif`, `elsif`...

Comment: Ah you have many many parameters? You might want to do something like tom L is recommending.

Comment: No, I have 1 parameter or 0. The unic parameter is the same for all the functions.

Comment: ah, well you might just be stuck checking each function if the parameter exists.